# How to change users home directory?

Tags: 14.04, users, user-management, adduser, multiple-users

I want to create new user or change one of the current users home directory from /home/user2 to /media/user1/secondary.

I already tried this solution here "[How to change the default parent directory for a new users home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524052/how-to-change-the-default-parent-directory-for-a-new-users-home-folder)" but still having the same issue when creating new users (home directory is still created in /home).

Thank you.

Comment: If /media is a NTFS filesystem you -can- -not- -do- -that-: ntfs does not let you set the permissions required for `/home/`. You can only store the directories in /home/$USER/ on a filesystem that is not EXT and you can so that by editing `~./config/users-dirs.dirs`.

Comment: @Rinzwind
Ahaa.. thank  you for this explanation. I actually testing this on my laptop "NTFS" partition before I apply it on the server which have EXT4 partitions. I don't get this part "you can so that by editing ~./config/users-dirs.dirs" .. can you clarify please?

Comment: open that file with gedit and it will all become clear: Change the directory to a hardcoded version and you can create the directories on that location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install **Users and Groups** by typing this into a terminal window:

   sudo apt install gnome-system-tools
2. Open **Users and Groups**
3. Click on the user you want to move.  (Note:  You cannot move your own directory.  You must do it from another user account that has admin privileges.)
4. Click the **Advanced Settings** button.

[image]

5. Type in the admin password
6. Click on the **Advanced** tab.
7. Type the new home directory path in the **Home Directory** text box.
8. Click **OK**

[image]

9. Click the **Copy Old Files** button, and you are done.  I WOULD NOT delete the old directory yet.  Verify the new directory is working properly first.

Once you find everything is working good, you can then delete the old directory, if you so choose.